# XOR use in MIPS Assembly

Tags: assembly, mips, xor

Okay, I'm pretty sure I've used up all variations of possible XOR use to exchange $s0 with $s1, however, I still can't get it to work! It's MIPS Assembly and I'm using MARS. Please could somebody provide me a solution?

You will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you asking about the [XOR swap algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm)?

Comment: why don't just use simple moves? It's cleaner and most probably faster in modern architectures

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you try

```
xor $s0, $s0, $s1
xor $s1, $s0, $s1
xor $s0, $s0, $s1
```